# Resizing the height and Width of a Picture while saving it to docx file in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Selenium API to take screen shot of a web page. After taking the screenshot, I am pasting the same to a word document using docx-python API. 
But, the size of the screenshot taken is too big. I would like to trim the height and width of the image(without losing any content of image). Can I reduce the image height and width. I don't want to use PIL API to trim the image. Please suggest, if we have any other option.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://news.google.com/?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en')
browser.maximize_window()
browser.save_screenshot('screenshot.png') 

doc = docx.Document()
doc.add_heading('Agreement: ' + AG + ' - Group: ' + GP + '\n')
doc.add_picture('screenshot.png')
doc.save('C:\\Users\\sds\\Documents\\' + AG + '-' + GP + '.docx')
```

Comment: Can it be done using 'OPENCV' ?  Does Python 3 support 'OpenCV' ?